# Value of volatile variable doesn't change in multi-thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, backgroundworker, volatile

I have a winform application that runs in background with a `BackgroundWorker` that has an infinite loop that execute something every hour. My UI `Form` class is something like this:

```
public partial class frmAutoScript : Form
{
    private volatile bool _isDownloading = false;
    private bool IsDownloading { get { return this._isDownloading; } set { this._isDownloading = value; } }

    public frmAutoScript()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.RunAutoSynchronization();
    }

    private void RunAutoSynchronization()
    {
        bool isDownloading = this.IsDownloading;

        BackgroundWorker bgwDownloader = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgwDownloader.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgwDownloader.ProgressChanged += (sndr, evnt) =>
        {
            if (evnt.ProgressPercentage == 2)
                isDownloading = this.IsDownloading;
            else
            {
                this.IsDownloading = evnt.ProgressPercentage == 1;
                isDownloading = this.IsDownloading;
            }
        };
        bgwDownloader.DoWork += (sndr, evnt) =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 16 &&
                        DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            bgwDownloader.ReportProgress(2);
                            if (!isDownloading)
                            {
                                bgwDownloader.ReportProgress(1);
                                new Downloader().Download();
                            }
                            bgwDownloader.ReportProgress(0);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
                }
            };
        bgwDownloader.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

And in that `frmAutoScript`, I also have a button named `btnDownload` that when clicked, it will download and change the value of the `volatile` varialbe `_isDownloading`. The event of the button is something like this:

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsDownloading)
        MessageBox.Show("A download is currently ongoing. Please wait for the download to finish.",
            "Force Download", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    else
    {
        this.IsDownloading = true;
        BackgroundWorker bgwDownloader = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgwDownloader.DoWork += (sndr, evnt) =>
        {
            try
            {
                new Downloader().Download();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occur during download. Please contact your system administrator.\n Exception: " +
                    ex.GetType().ToString() + "\nError Message:\n" + ex.Message + " Stack Trace:\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Download Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        };
        bgwDownloader.RunWorkerCompleted += (sndr, evnt) =>
        {
            this.IsDownloading = false;
        };
        bgwDownloader.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

But when I click the button `btnDownload` and the `_isDownloading` is set to `true`, and when the system time hit the `4:00 PM`, the `new Downloader().Download();` is executed again eventhough the `_isDownloading` is set to true. Why was it like this?

My code is in C#, framework 4, project is in winforms, build in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not testing against the `volatile` field - it is testing against `isDownloading`, which *looks* like a "local", but (because it is captured) is in fact a regular (non-`volatile`) field. So: either use some kind of memory barrier, or force that to be a volatile read. Or more simply: get rid of `isDownloading` ***completely***, and check against the property.

Incidentally, the cache-defeating properties of `volatile` are **not** the intent of the keyword, but rather: a consequence. It'll work, but *personally* I'd suggest writing the code to work **by intent** rather than by consequence, perhaps using either a simple `lock` or something like `Interlocked`.

Comment: So what is the intent of the keyword?

Comment: @zmbq very complex, poorly understood, and relating to CPU instruction re-ordering; here's the words from ECMA 334: http://pastie.org/pastes/3981577/text . I'm pretty confident in my threading, and simply: `volatile` is not the semantic I usually use to guarantee the behaviour

Comment: I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645755%28v=vs.71%29.aspx . I'm probably missing something, because I can't see why volatiles don't have the purpose everybody thinks they do.

Comment: @zmbq then maybe allow Eric Lippert to add a word: see [Atomicity, volatility and immutability are different, part three](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx), the last paragraph starting "Frankly"

Comment: No argument there... Perhaps there should be a `synchronized` keyword that automatically puts a lock around all field access. It won't save you from deadlocks, though.

Comment: @zmbq at the end of the day, threading is sufficiently complex that the only sensible way to approach is slowly and carefully. Extra keywords cannot in any way remove the need to stop and think.